# element does not center horizontally and icons do not appear (css)

Tags: html, css, text, icons, center

I cannot find out why text1 does not center horizontally and why the icons do not appear (I have only a black point instead of blue icon and 
circle).

```
<div id="texte_services">     
text1
</div>
  <div class="flex-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <p class="contenu">
            <img src="../Images/screen.png" alt="screen">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>                  
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>   
        </td>
    </tr>               
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>
        </td>            
    </tr>       
            <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>
        </td>            
    </tr>     
</table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#texte_services
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

article
{
margin-right: 20px;
flex: 3;
}

.ico_categorie
{
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 8px;
}

h3, p
{
margin: 20px;
}


#flex-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

Comment: not sure you have included css file as external. but css which you have post is without <style> tag.

Comment: Have you linked font awesome library to your html file?

Comment: Have you imported the Font Awesome library properly?

Comment: https://codepen.io/abhayincreasingly/pen/mxYKWR?editors=1100 checkout this after importing the Font Awesome Library, icons work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because you didnt include the link to font-awesome.min.css I just added it and everything works fine.

```css
#texte_services
{
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
justify-content: center;
text-align: center;
}

article
{
margin-right: 20px;
flex: 3;
}

.ico_categorie
{
vertical-align: middle;
margin-right: 8px;
}

h3, p
{
margin: 20px;
}


#flex-container {
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
margin-top: -20px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="texte_services">
text1
</div>

<div class="flex-container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="column">
        <p class="contenu">
            <img src="../Images/screen.png" alt="screen">
        </p>
    </div>
</div>


<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>


        </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>
        </td>

    </tr>


            <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="bullet">
            </div>
           <span class="blueText"><i class="fa fa-line-chart fa-lg"></i>
           </span>
            <span class="bluePoint">&bull;
            </span>
            <span class="titleText">
            </span>
        </td>

        <td>
            <h3>UX design
            </h3>
            <p>text2
            </p>
        </td>

    </tr>


</table>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks :) now I have the icon, but I am still missing the circle around the icon

Comment: Did you define circle around the icon?? should you want to define a circle around the icon, add this css  .blueText{ width: 200px; height:200px; border-radius:50%; background-color:blue; color:#fff}